# How to make a Binding in code?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Custom:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Background="{x:Null}" x:Name="datagrid" 
                                 DataContext="{StaticResource dataSetPartner}" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Partner}"....
```

and

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataSetPartner" MethodName="PartnerStat" ObjectType="{x:Type loc:DataSetCreator}"  />
```

this is great work, but I need to write a code...

my code not is work:

```
adatagrid.DataContext = null;
datagrid.DataContext = this.Resources["dataSetPartner"];

Binding b = new Binding("DataContext");
b.Source = datagrid;
b.Path = new PropertyPath("Partner");
b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
datagrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
```

why?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get an exception? Does your Visual Studio Output window show any binding errors? BTW, you can use `Binding()` instead of `Binding("DataContext")`. The parameter sets the path, which you overwrite anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ObjectDataProvider is used in XAML to indicate a data source.  You specify the type and the method to call. There's no need to use the ObjectDataProvider in your code however, because you can call the method directly.

---

```
  var dsc = new DataSetCreator();
  this.DataContext = dsc.PartnerStat();
  // bind a textblock
  Binding b = new Binding("FirstName");
  textBlock1.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);
  // bind the datagrid
  // don't specify a path, it will bind to the entire collection

  var b1 = new Binding(); 
  dataGrid1.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, b1);
```

Comment: Great! but the correct code in my case :                     datagrid.DataContext = DataSetCreator.PartnerStat();
                    var b1 = new Binding("Partner");
                    datagrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, b1);

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I don't know your object model so I had to guess at the correct names.